# Complex Least Squares With Magnitude Equality Constraints

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-system, least-squares

For $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{C}^N$, I'd like to solve the following problem:

$$
\mathbf{x}^\ast = \arg \min_{\mathbf{x}} \Vert \mathbf{Ax-b} \Vert_2  \,\,\,\,\,\,  \mathrm{s.t.} \,\,\,\,\, \Vert x_i \Vert_2 = a_i,  \,\,\,\, i = 0, \dots, N-1,
$$

where $a_i \in \mathbb{R}$. The above is a least-squares problem where the magnitude of the elements of $\mathbf{x}$ are fixed and only their phase may vary.

Can anyone point me in the direction of how to solve this? I have tried adding the equality constraints as a penalty term to the cost function, but had no success. Though I have not found anything yet, I am hoping that is a well-studied problem with a known solution.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Interesting problem. No idea how to solve it. :-) It's non-convex and in a particularly difficult manner. (For instance, if $x$ were real, one could search the $2^N$ combinations exhaustively at least.)

Answer (score 0):

Really nice and interesting question.
I tried, at first, solving it on the Real domain.

A brute force approach is my reference and I tried working with the following cost function:

$$ \arg \min_{x} f \left( x \right) = \arg \min_{x} \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \frac{\lambda}{2} \left\| \operatorname{abs} \left( x \right) - a \right\|_{2}^{2} $$

Where $ \operatorname{abs} \left( x \right) $ is element wise.

The derivative is given by:

$$ \frac{d}{d x} f \left( x \right) = {A}^{T} \left( A x - b \right) + \lambda \operatorname{sign} \left( x \right) \left( \operatorname{abs} \left( x \right) - a \right) $$

I tried Gradient Descent where I raise the value of $ \lambda $ at each iteration.
It worked not so bad, but even the sign of the solution wasn't consistent with the optimal solution.

My intermediate code is given [here](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/tree/master/Mathematics/Q1781856).

I will try another 2 approaches:

1. Using Iterative Least Squares like approach.
2. Using [Orthogonal Matching Pursuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_pursuit) (OMP) like approach.